# Consuming REST API using a webview with authentication header

Tags: android, webview, basic-authentication

I am working on REST API with "POST" type, I want to consume it by using WebView. I am using webView.postUrl() but I also need authentication header with my POST request which I am not able to do.

My code is given below, along with the information needed for my Rest api with POST type. Kindly guide me to solve this problem.

// Here is my block of code for using POST type Rest API

```
private static final String URL_STRING = "https://derxxxlist.net/uxxxco/Surxxxe/Membxxxhip/Axxxxin";

    public void postData(WebView mWebView) throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", "xxx@aaa.com"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "qwerasdf"));

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_STRING);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String data = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
        mWebView.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8");

    }
```

// Here I am passing my webView in my above method:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                    postData(webView);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }}).start();
```

What I want is to pass authentication header along with my above post API.

// My Authentication header

```
"authorization", "amx A93reRTUJHsxxxxxxxxxxCgps102ciuabc="
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header of the Http request using setHeader

```
httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "amx A93reRTUJHsxxxxxxxxxxCgps102ciuabc=");
```